# Passing variable to tr:contains using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am playing with jQquery selector and trying to pass variable value, for example the below code works fine and removing the value where it contain 155.

```
 $('#stdtable tr:contains(155)').remove();
```

But I have a hard time when storing this value into variable and passing to `tr:contain` selector for dynamically removing.

For example

```
  var myval = '155'
  $('#stdtable tr:contains(myval)').remove();
```

The above code is not working when passing variable value to `tr:contain`, please anyone correct if I am missing anything, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code the "myval" is not interpreted as a variable, but as literal text. Try this instead:

```
var myval = '155'
$('#stdtable tr:contains('+myval+')').remove();
```

Comment: +1: Also good practice to add double-quotes to cater for values with special characters (might occur later). e.g. `$('#stdtable tr:contains("'+myval+'")')`